# unrecognized selector sent to instance NSArray/NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, nsarray

I creating a game in Cocos2D 2, but my issue is with NSArray/NSMutableArray.

A class called SocketManager that manages the socket class which is derived from CCSprite.  Socket only has extra member variable called row which is an int.  The SocketManager keeps an array with all the Sockets sprites that are within the game.

In the game class I have this code to add the sockets to the manager:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {

    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

        Socket *socket =[Socket spriteWithFile:@"Tile_Socket.png"];


        socket.row = i;            
        socket.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);

         /* Shortend to cut out useless code */

        [socketsManager addSocket:socket];
        [self addChild:socket];

    }
    }
```

This is the SocketsManger add function:

```
-(void)addSocket:(CCSprite *)socket {

[sockets addObject:sockets];
 }
```

Later on in the game in the update function it checks if the row wants to be changed and calls the SocketManager's function called :

```
-(NSArray *)searchSocketByRow:(int)row; {

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Socket *socket in sockets)
    CCLOG(@"Row: %i", socket.row);
   // if ([socket row] == row)
    //    [array addObject:socket];

  //  CCLOG(@"Found %i sockets.", [array count]);
  //  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:[array mutableCopy]];
  }
```

When I try to call socket.row or [socket row] I get the error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method looks wrong try to change it to:

```
-(void)addSocket:(CCSprite *)socket {

[sockets addObject:socket];
 }
```

You try to add array to array but you want to add CCSprite object.
It should help.

Comment: Wow I missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra S in the mix.  In the add socket function change this

```
[sockets addObject:sockets];
```

to

```
[sockets addObject:socket];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  [sockets addObject:socket];
```

without s at the object you want to add